# Customize ios keyboard to show numeric keyboard

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, html, cordova

I am working on a hybrid apps where I need to display numeric keyboard with dot and comma for iOS. I tried the pattern [0-9] with type as number. It works for android but does not show dot/comma for iOS. Anyone has any idea how to achieve this for iOS ? i tried searching for cordova plugin. Did not get any. I created a custom keyboard in angular. But it is having some delay for iOS when i provide any input.
I need below attached keyboard in html5 input field. For ios i don't get dots using 
"input type="number" min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*"".

[Please see attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V58n8.png)

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 14):

**2019 Update**

For anyone coming from Google looking for a working solution, this is now possible with the **inputmode** attribute as of iOS 12.3.

So something like `<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="decimal">` will show the numeric keyboard with a dot/comma for Android/iOS 12.3+, and the regular numeric keyboard for older iOS devices - note that inputmode has to be set to "decimal".

More info available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode).

Answer (score 1):

its will  works Android and iOS

```
  <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
```

Comment: I tried with this . In android it works fine. But in ios i am not getting comma and dots. Mine is currency field . So I need to have both this chars. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: if you want keyboard  with comma and dots  just use  <input type="number">

Comment: iOS numeric keyboard look like this. Platforms can have diversity. I think Android and iOS works different for keyboard.  http://www.globalnerdy.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/twitter-2.png

Comment: Using number i gets other special chars which I don't want. I want a simple keyboard with 0-9 ,dot and backspace. I can use number and restrict users to enter any chars other than i mentioned. But that I want to be my last option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like,

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
```

**Update :**

You can do something like,

```
 EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
 myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Or:

```
 <input type="tel" />
```

or

```
 <input type="number" step="0.01">
```

You can refer [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684855/force-ios-numeric-keyboard-with-custom-currency-pattern).

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I tried with this . In android it works fine. But in ios i am not getting comma and dots. Mine is currency field . So I need to have both this chars. Thanks for the reply.